# Can't Append to the File

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, append

I'm trying to write this program where if the user opens an existing file, they have the option to either read, start over, or append to it, but the append option isn't working. Why is that?

````
from sys import argv

file = input("Please open a file: ")
try:
    file = open(file, "r+")
    choice = input("""
    What would you like to do with this file?
    A) Read file
    B) Delete file and start over
    C) Append file
    """).lower().rstrip()
    if choice in "a":
        print(file.read())
    elif choice in "b":
        print("What would you like to write?")
        file.write(input())
    elif choice in "c":
        file = open(file, "a")
        print("What would you like to write?\n")
        file.write(input())
except:
    print("This is a new file.\n")
    file = open(file, "w")
    print("What would you like to save in this file?")
    file.write(input())```
````

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  This post contains a lot of unrelated code.

Comment: I think it's necessary to show all of it because I'm trying to give the user the option to not append. The last elif is where the append option is

Comment: Your generic exception handling will swallowed any exception that is raised, making debugging impossible.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you are assigning the variable `file` to the input of the user in `input("Please open a file: ")`, but right after this you assign it to be the txt file in `file = open(file, "r+")`.

So, when you write `file = open(file, "a")`, the compiler is reading `file` not as the user input, but the opened txt file.

What you should do is to give different names to the different variables

```py
from sys import argv

filename = input("Please open a file: ")
try:
    file = open(filename, "r+")
    choice = input("""
    What would you like to do with this file?
    A) Read file
    B) Delete file and start over
    C) Append file
    """).lower().rstrip()
    if choice in "aA":
        print(file.read())
    elif choice in "bB":
        print("What would you like to write?")
        file.write(input())
    elif choice in "cC":
        file.close()
        file = open(filename, "a")
        print("What would you like to write?\n")
        file.write(input())
except:
    print("This is a new file.\n")
    file = open(file, "w")
    print("What would you like to save in this file?")
    file.write(input())
```

**UPDATE**

As OneLiner said in the comments, you should always close the files after opening them. This can be easily done by using, as he said, `with open(filename, "a") as file:`. Besides that, I noticed two more things.

First, you shouldn't use `except` alone, because if I try, for example, to press `ctrl+c`, it will fall into this exception. What you should write instead is `except FileNotFoundError`, so that if there is no such file, this exception will be raised.

The second thing I noticed is that you are using the name `file` as the name of a variable. The problem is that `file` is already being used in python for another thing, so it would be better to use another name. In that case the code would be:

```py
from sys import argv

filename = input("Please open a file: ")

try:
    with open(filename, "r+") as file_txt:
        pass

    choice = input("""
    What would you like to do with this file?
    A) Read file
    B) Delete file and start over
    C) Append file
    """).lower().rstrip()

    if choice == "a":
        with open(filename, "r") as file_txt: 
            print(file_txt.read())
    elif choice == "b":
        content = input("What would you like to write?\n")
        with open(filename, "w") as file_txt:
            file_txt.write(content)
    elif choice == "c":
        with open(filename, "a") as file_txt:
            content = input("What would you like to write?\n")
            file_txt.write(content)
            
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("This is a new file.\n")
    with open(filename, "w") as file_txt:
        content = input("What would you like to save in this file?\n")
        file_txt.write(content)
```

Comment: Also open your file in the correct mode for what you are doing and close it when done. You may want to consider using "with open()" statements in each if statement.

Answer (score -1):

Using `"r+"` allows you to read and write, but the pointer is at the beginning, meaning that "appending" doesn't actually exist. If I'm not mistaken, there's no way to open a file for reading, writing, and appending, because there's no way to move the pointer along the file.

To get around this, I would suggest opening the file separately in each `if` clause.

If the person wants to **read** the file, then open it using `"r"`.
If the person wants to **write** to the file, then open it using `"w"`, and if the person wants to **append** to it, then open it using `"a"`. More options, such as combinations of two can be found [here](https://stackabuse.com/file-handling-in-python/).

The code:

```
try:
    #removed:
    #file = open(file, "r+")
    choice = input("""
    What would you like to do with this file?
    A) Read file
    B) Delete file and start over
    C) Append file
    """).lower().rstrip()
    if choice in "a":
        file = open(file, "r")
        print(file.read())
    elif choice in "b":
        file = open(file, "w")
        print("What would you like to write?")
        file.write(input())
    elif choice in "c":
        file = open(file, "a")
        print("What would you like to write?\n")
        file.write(input())
except:
    print("This is a new file.\n")
    file = open(file, "w")
    print("What would you like to save in this file?")
    file.write(input())
```